# Not able to login to salesforce with deactivated login flow

Tags: visual-workflow, login, visual-flows, login-errors, loginflow

I deactivated a login flow in Developer edition and now when I log in to salesforce I get the below error and it is not letting me sign in. please confirm if is there any solution to this problem.

[image]

Is there any way to login to the developer edition now

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove it from Setup > Login Flows, not only deactivate it from Flows because it's still looking for the flow to be executed.

Comment: Thank you for responding but how would I remove it from setup I am not able to login to salesforce

Comment: Oh, yeah. Didn't think of that. If you have a user with another license type, you could try to enter with that one and see if it has enough permissions to remove the login flow. If it was the only user it's harder. I remember something like that happened to a colleague a few months ago and I think he was able to add a user from the data loader with the Sys Admin profile without logging in and then he could log in with that new user but I can't find that process online. I'll let you know if I find it.

Comment: Now that I've done a little research it seems more plausible to be able to add the user from Workbench. And you could log in there because the login flow will not be executed there. There's a unit in trailhead where you add an account through Workbench, I think you could make it work for User as well.

Comment: I also just faced this issue with my Developer edition. I deactivated the flow with removing the login flow completely. Tried logging with workbench, even there it is taking me through the Login Flow. I am also not able to skip the login flow . I even tried VS CODe, there also it is forcing me to go through login flow.  Called Support, they are not willing to help because this is just a Developer edition. Now i have to purchase a subscription for one full year

Answer (score 0):

you may raise a case with SF and get the login flow deleted. I was stuck with same issue and got it resolved by SF support.

raise a case for dev account: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?support=mycases